# how to map object to datatable row for displaying in datagrid?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Here is a function to set the value to a custom object from `DB` `resultset`, and then i want to return a `datatable` again.

```
public DataTable getProductsTable(DataSet productData)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        dt.Columns.Add("catid", typeof(string));

        for (i = 0; i <= productData.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            productData dataObj = new productData();
            dataObj.id = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
            dataObj.barcode = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["barcode"].ToString();
            dataObj.catid = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["catid"].ToString();
            dataObj.entity_id = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["entity_id"].ToString();
            dataObj.sku = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["sku"].ToString();
            dataObj.name = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
            dataObj.price = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["price"].ToString();
            dataObj.final_price = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["final_price"].ToString();
            dataObj.qty = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["qty"].ToString();
            dataObj.is_in_stock = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["is_in_stock"].ToString();
            dataObj.special_from_date = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_from_date"].ToString();
            dataObj.special_to_date = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_to_date"].ToString();
            dataObj.status = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["status"].ToString();
            dataObj.parent_id = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["parent_id"].ToString();
            dataObj.type_id = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["type_id"].ToString();
            //data.Add(dataObj);
            dt.Rows.Add(dataObj);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

But it does not work, after i run above function, all `columns` are displayed but all `rows` are not displayed with no value, the first column only display `namespace.productData`. Anyone how to fix this?

https://s27.postimg.org/li3lmr99f/test.png

Comment: So the input to the method is a DataSet and expected output is a table also you are not doing anything with `dataObj` then why not a simple return like this:  `return productData.Tables[0];`

Comment: something i may do later in productData object

Comment: So. you get a `DataSet` called `productData`, and you have a class called `productData`? That would give you a lot of problems. Also, check that you really have data in the dataset

Comment: @hkguile: Try to come up with a clear question

Comment: Also, for this to work, `productData` must be a `DataRow`. Otherwise, you can't add a class to a `DataTable` that way

Comment: add a image.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dt` has only one column (`"catid"`). Add more columns for each property like below :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable()
{
   Columns = { "id", "barcode", "catid", etc...}
};
```

`DataTable.Rows` is of type `DataRowCollection` which has 2 overloads of `Add` method:

```
1. public void Add(DataRow row)
2. public DataRow Add(params object[] values)
```

`dt.Rows.Add(dataObj);` uses the second overload and adds a single value in the first column. To add values correctly use

```
dt.Rows.Add(dataObj.id, dataObj.barcode, etc... );
```